# UITouch object behaving oddly

Tags: iphone

I wanted to get points where user is touching on the screen therefore I wrote following code which will fire when user will touch somewhere on the screen

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] init]; 
    touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint([dob frame], point)) {
        [self showDatePickerforDOB:YES];
    }
}
```

but this code is giving run time error. Upon debugging it was revealed that locationInView is not recognized as a function of touch object on the other hand it is documented in iphone class reference documentation. When I changed code to exclude alloc i.e
UITouch *touch;
touch = [touches anyObject];
then locationInView is perfectly working fine. Any ideas why UITouch *touch = [[UITouch alloc] init];   is giving runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the reason why there was an error. It was because of line

```
CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self];
```

when I changed it to `CGPoint point = [touch locationInView:self.view];` runtime error was removed. The reason is that locationInView function takes UIView as its parameter and on the other hand i was giving it a delegate i.e 'self'.

so self.view solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not alloc and init the touch pointer, the correct code should be:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point  = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (CGRectContainsPoint([dob frame], point)) {
        [self showDatePickerforDOB:YES];
    }
}
```

`[touches anyObject]` will return an autorelease object so you don't need to alloc and init the touch pointer.